# Im having a code error, while doing a code for a circular link list

Tags: c++, xcode, data-structures

Im having a problem finding the solution on my code, it was running okay, but while I as editing the main to Run the code, something might have change. so now I'm having this error on my code that says: this' argument to member function 'isEmpty' has type 'const CircularLinkedList', but function is not marked const

This is the part of the code where the error is popping.

```
//Copy Constructor
 template <typename T>
 CircularLinkedList<T>::CircularLinkedList(const CircularLinkedList& c1)
{
    if (!c1.isEmpty())
{
    Node<T>* curr = c1.frst;

    //Iterating through elements until we encounter home node again
    while (curr->next != first)
    {
        insert(curr->data);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
  }
 }
```

The following code I didn't originally have it on my main-menu to run the code but once I put it on it the error pop up. I'm no sure if this has something to do with it. but as a reference here is the code that I added. I didn't have any error before this code.

```
int printMenu();

 // InsertList inserts an item into the list parameter
 void insertListItem ( CircularLinkedList<int> & );

 // deletes the first occurrence from the list parameter
void deleteOne ( CircularLinkedList<int> & );

// deletes all the occurrence from  list parameter
void deleteAll ( CircularLinkedList<int> & );

 //return the length of the list
 int totalCount( CircularLinkedList<int> & );

// searchItem searches for an item in the list parameter
void searchItem ( CircularLinkedList<int>  );

 // return the number of occurrences of a given item
 int totalOccurence (CircularLinkedList<int> & );
```

Comment: can you please share what insert is doing? Also, the line of code where you are checking first ... it should be c1.first. Right? So, please copy paste the code otherwise it is hard to understand if it was compiling at first place.

Comment: the code was compiling at the beginning. I started to have the error only once I add the other code to run the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory: in your `CircularLinkedList<T>::CircularLinkedList` copy constructor, the parameter is marked `const`.

You can only use its method that are defined as `const`. So change your `isEmpty` definition to something like

```
bool isEmpty() const {...}
```

After all, checking if the list is empty should not modify that list.

Comment: well I do have as   bool isEmpty();      but how could I implement the cons{...}

Comment: @Karla looks like you got it (since you've accepted the answer). Please let me know if you still need help.